# How to proof those inequalities

Tags: inequality

My teacher give me some hard exercises. Could you guy help me with some.
Ex 1:
Given $a,b,c\gt0$ ; $a+b+c=3$.
Proof:
$$ \sqrt{ \frac {ab} {c} }+ \sqrt {\frac{bc} {a}} + \sqrt {\frac{ca} {b}} \ge  3$$

Ex 2:
Given $a,b,c>0$.
Proof:
$${\left(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}\right)}^2\ge(a+b+c)\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\right)$$

Ex 3: 
Given $a,b,c>0$.
Proof $$\frac{b+c}{a}+\frac{c+a}{b}+\frac{a+b}{c}\ge4\left(\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{c+a}+\frac{c}{a+b}\right)$$
In the first exercise, I tried to add them up. That's mean we have to proof the following statement:
$$ \frac{ab+bc+ca}{\sqrt{abc}}\ge 3$$
I am stuck at this point.
In the third exercise:
$$\frac{b+c}{a}+\frac{c+a}{b}+\frac{a+b}{c} = \frac ba +\frac ca +\frac cb +\frac ab +\frac ac +\frac bc $$
Using AM-GM we get $$\frac ba +\frac ab \ge 2 \sqrt {\frac ba \frac ab} = 2 $$ and so on
$$\Rightarrow \frac{b+c}{a}+\frac{c+a}{b}+\frac{a+b}{c} \ge 6 $$
We need to proof the following lemma :
$$\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{c+a}+\frac{c}{a+b}\le\frac 32$$
However the lemma is wrong. The Nesbitt inequality states :
$$\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{c+a}+\frac{c}{a+b}\ge\frac 32$$
I am totally stuck right here.
(Sorry for the bad English. I am a Vietnamese and only 14 years old.)

Comment: this is not a forum for you to find solution without sharing your idea and    show where you stuck

Comment: I am very sorry. This is my first question on stackexchange and i haven't known the rules yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For exercise $2$ expand the terms :

$$\frac{a^2}{b^2}+\frac{b^2}{c^2}+\frac{c^2}{a^2}+2\cdot \left (\frac{a}{c}+\frac{b}{a}+\frac{c}{b} \right )\geq 3+\frac{a}{c}+\frac{b}{a}+\frac{c}{b}+\frac{c}{a}+\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}$$ or after simplification :

$$\frac{a^2}{b^2}+\frac{b^2}{c^2}+\frac{c^2}{a^2}+\frac{a}{c}+\frac{b}{a}+\frac{c}{b} \geq 3+\frac{c}{a}+\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}$$

Now use AM-GM :

$$\frac{a^2}{b^2}+\frac{b^2}{c^2} \geq 2\sqrt{\frac{a^2}{b^2} \cdot \frac{b^2}{c^2}}=2 \cdot \frac{a}{c}$$

Do the same for the other and add them to get :

$$\frac{a^2}{b^2}+\frac{b^2}{c^2}+\frac{c^2}{a^2} \geq \frac{c}{a}+\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}$$

Also from AM-GM :

$$\frac{a}{c}+\frac{b}{a}+\frac{c}{b} \geq 3 \sqrt[3]{\frac{a}{c} \cdot \frac{b}{a} \cdot \frac{c}{b}}=3$$

Now add these two inequalities to get the conclusion .

Answer (score 2):

By AM-GM, $m^2+p^2+n^2 \geq mn+np+pm$

So, $(m+n+p)^2 \geq 3(mn+np+pm)$

Now, put $\sqrt{\frac{ab}{c}}=m$ and so on.

Also for 2)

$\frac{a^2}{2b^2}+\frac{1}{2} \geq \frac{a}{b}$

$\frac{b^2}{2c^2}+\frac{1}{2} \geq \frac{b}{c}$

$\frac{c^2}{2a^2}+\frac{1}{2} \geq \frac{c}{a}$

$\frac{a^2}{2b^2}+\frac{b^2}{2c^2}+\frac{c^2}{2a^2} \geq \frac{3}{2}$.

$\frac{a}{c}+\frac{b}{a}+\frac{c}{b} \geq 3$

Adding all the inequalities and then adding $\frac{a}{c}+\frac{b}{a}+\frac{c}{b}$ to both sides you get the desired inequality

Adding all the

Comment: I have edited to include solution for ex 2)